# Discrete Fourier Transform Relation between two signals

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I'm struggling into show the relation between $\hat g[k]$ and $\hat h[k]$ given $g[n]=(-1)^nh[n]$, where $h[n]$ is a discrete signal, let's say with $0\le n <N$. I made some computations that I show you

\begin{align*}
\hat g[k]&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}g[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^nh[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N} \\
    &=\sum\limits_{n \text{ even}}h[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}-\sum\limits_{n \text{ odd}}h[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}
\end{align*}

and the same hold also for $\hat h[k]$ since the functions are switchable

\begin{align*}
    \hat h[k]&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^ng[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N} \\
    &=\sum\limits_{n \text{ even}}g[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}-\sum\limits_{n \text{ odd}}g[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}
\end{align*}

Now from here I tried various ways but I cannot find a fine relation between them. I ended up with these

$$
  \hat g[k]+\hat h[k] = 2\sum\limits_{n \text{ even}}h[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}
$$

$$
    \hat g[k]-\hat h[k] = -2\sum\limits_{n \text{ odd}}h[n]e^{-i2\pi kn/N}
$$

But I'm not sure if these can be considered as a solution, maybe I miss something else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^n = e^{-j2\pi k(nN/2)/N}$

Comment: Ok, why? Where did you get it?

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally introduced $k$ in the equation, it should not be there. The equation is a direct application of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

Comment: Ok I thought that. I'll try some computations.